# Cannot Open Firefox browser in foreground in jenkins?

Tags: selenium, firefox, jenkins, automation, sikuli

I am not able to open firefox browser in foreground when running using jenkins. It is being opened in the background and script is executed. But I need it to open in foreground to perform sikuli testing.

Comment: Is this on remote machine? Keep in mind that Sikuli will not work in headless machines.

Comment: How is Jenkins started? Is this Windows machine? Is it configured as Windows service?

Comment: @EugeneS . I am able to run sikuli on a remote machine through jenkins. But the problem I am encountering is firefox is opening in background. Locally firefox is displayed on the front screen. But in remotely it is at the back. And I need it to be displayed in front so that sikuli can find the images. Is there anything that can be done to bring the browser as front screen using jenkins?

Comment: When you say in the background, what do you mean? Is this blocked by another application window? Is it just starting the process but you get no visual?

Comment: @EugeneS Yes it is starting the browser behind all the other applications. But I am not able to see the app running in front.  I tried minimizing all the other applications before running the code. Now the browser is the only application visible on the screen. But that is not an effective solution. Anything on your mind.